# Combinatorics/Probability, Choosing from group of People

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

[image]

I attempted to do this problem and I do have some guesses and trying to see whether they are right. Can you please correct if I'm wrong and explain. would really appreciate it.

For a)
I have C(8,4) *C(9,2). So, 8 choose 4 * 9 choose 2.

For b)
I have C(17,4) - C(8,4) - (9,9) [total - men - different ways to choose women.]

Answer (score 2):

If it's a four person committee, then you choose two men given that two women are chosen. So $\binom{9}{2} * \binom{8}{2}$ is your answer for (a).

For (b), break it up into cases. (a) gives you the case where there are two women. There are $\binom{9}{4}$ ways to choose a committee of four women. For three women, we have $\binom{9}{3} * \binom{8}{1}$. Each case is disjoint, so you add them up:

$\binom{9}{4} + \binom{9}{3} * \binom{8}{1} + \binom{9}{2} * \binom{8}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

a. The answer should be: $8 \choose 2$$\times$ $9 \choose 2$.

b. The answer is: $8 \choose 2$$\times$$9 \choose 2$ + $8 \choose 1$$\times$$9 \choose 3$ + $9 \choose 4$.

Answer (score 0):

a)
$\binom{8}{2}*\binom{9}{2}$

I guess C(8,5) is a typo.

b)
$\binom{17}{4}-\binom{8}{4}-\binom{9}{1}*\binom{8}{3}$

total - all men - *1 woman 3 men*

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to the party but why isn't **a)** You need to pick 2 female members: $\binom92$ and for the $2$ renaming positions we can choose between $8$ and $9-2=7$ female members (nothing specified that we need to pick men) so we have for a) $\binom{9}{2} * \binom{8 + 7}{2} = \binom{9}{2} * \binom{15}{2} = 3780$

and for question **b)** it is either 2 female and 2 rest or 3 females and 1 rest and 4 females and 0 rest so : $\binom{9}{2} * \binom{15}{2} + \binom{9}{3} * \binom{14}{1} + \binom{9}{4} * \binom{13}{0} = 5082$